# R : pass Graph as parameter to a function

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a decent looking graph ,which I plotted using

```
r <- ggplot(data=data2.Gurgaon,aes(x=createdDate,y=count))+geom_point()
```

Now i want to higlight few points on the graph say 500,1000,5000 etc..
so ,I am trying to write a function , in which i can pass point I want to mark
Below is the function I have written

```
graphPoint <- function(graph,point) {
  g <- graph
  g <- g+geom_point(aes(x=createdDate[point],y=count[point]),pch=1,size=8,col='black')
  g <- g+ geom_point(aes(x=createdDate[point],y=count[point]),pch=16,size=5,col='red')
  g
}
```

when i am passing parameters

```
r -> graphPoint(r,500)
```

this is giving error

```
Error in lapply(X = x, FUN = "[", ..., drop = drop) : 
  object 'point' not found
```

i am not that great with R . Hope its possible , But I am missing at some small point .. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in a function? Otherwise you could add a 'highlight' variable to the original data, and colour your points/change the size by that.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an extremely subtle (and annoying...) problem in `ggplot`, although not a bug. The `aes(...)` function evaluates all symbols first in the context of the default dataset (e.g. it looks for columns with that name), and, if that fails *in the global environment*. It does not move up the calling chain, as you might justifiably expect it to. So in your case the symbol `point` is first evaluated in the context of `data2.Gurgaon`. Since there is no such column, it looks for `point` in the global environment, but *not* in the context of your `graphPoint(...)` function. Here is a demonstration:

```
df <- mtcars
library(ggplot2)
graphPoint <- function(graph,point) {
  g <- graph
  g <- g + geom_point(aes(x=wt[point],y=mpg[point]),pch=1,size=8,col='black')
  g <- g + geom_point(aes(x=wt[point],y=mpg[point]),pch=16,size=5,col='red')
  g
}

ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
point=10
graphPoint(ggp, 10)
```

[image]

The reason this works is because I defined `point` in the global environment; the `point` variable inside the function is being ignored (you can demonstrate that by calling the fn with something other than 10: you'll get the same plot).

The correct way around this is by subsetting the `data=...` argument, as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select a subset of the data within the aesthetics part of a ggplot function, as you are trying to do. However you can achieve this by extracting the original data from the `ggplot` object, subsetting it and using the subset in the rest of the function.

```
r <- ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=cyl,y=drat))+geom_point()

 graphPoint <- function(graph,point) {
  g <- graph
  data_subset <- g$data[point, ]
  g <- g+geom_point(data = data_subset, 
                    aes(x=cyl,y=drat),pch=1,size=8,col='black')
  g <- g+ geom_point(data = data_subset,
                     aes(x=cyl,y=drat),pch=16,size=5,col='red')
  g
 }

 graphPoint(r, point = 2)
```

PS for upcoming posts I would advise you to make a reproducible example by using data that is generally accessible, like the `mtcars` data. This would make it easier to help you out.

Comment: Your code does run, but it's not strictly true that "You cannot select a subset of the data within the aesthetics part of a ggplot function...". You can in fact. The reason OP's code fails is because he's using `point` in an `aes(...)` call *inside a function*.