# How to selectively map aesthetics (convex hulls) to ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to overlay convex hulls on-top of noisy data. I only want the hulls on the main clusters (and not the red outliers).

[image: Toy data]

**How would I plot every other hull while plotting all the points?**

In my workaround attempt, I accidentally made all the outliers disappeared. Additionally, the shapes (21-25) were distorted when plotting my actual data in a Shiny app.

Would this be solved by tinkering when building the stat, or by editing the mapping?

**Requirements:** I'd also like to keep things to `ggplot2` since this will all be wrapped up in a ShinyApp, and the hulls will be plotted if the user clicks on a checkbox. The number of cluster varies per graph, but the first one is ALWAYS the outlier.

**Data Generation**

```
library(dbscan)
library(ggplot2)
data("DS3")
DS3_cl <- hdbscan(DS3, minPts = 25)
DS3_comb <- DS3
DS3_comb$cluster <- as.character(DS3_cl$cluster)
```

**Graph functions/parameters**

```
cols <- c('#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#a65628','#f781bf','#999999','#ffff33') 
cols_2 <-  c(NA,'#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#a65628','#f781bf','#999999','#ffff33') 

StatChull <- ggproto("StatChull", Stat, 
                     compute_group = function(data, scales) {
                       data[chull(data$x, data$y), , drop = FALSE]
                     },
                     # Do the outlier removal around here?
                     required_aes = c("x", "y")
)

stat_chull <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "polygon",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatChull, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

**Plots**:

```
plot_1 <- ggplot(data = DS3_comb, aes(X, Y, color = cluster)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  theme_bw()

plot_2 <- plot_1 + stat_chull(fill = NA)
```

**Workaround Attempt:**

```
plot_3 <- ggplot(data = DS3_comb, aes(X,Y, fill = cluster, color = cluster)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols_2) +
  theme_bw()
```

**Sources consulted:**

- [R : pass Graph as parameter to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391334/r-pass-graph-as-parameter-to-a-function/32393746#32393746)
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html
- [stat_function and legends: create plot with two separate colour legends mapped to different variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219411/stat-function-and-legends-create-plot-with-two-separate-colour-legends-mapped-t)

  - Just started reading, but could be problematic with Shiny: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subset the data for that layer. For example

```
plot_1 + stat_chull(fill = NA, data=subset(DS3_comb,cluster!=0))
```

[image]

Comment: ... I overthought things. This also worked in the ShinyApp with brush over points!

Comment: Hey @MrFlick, I tried to make the color dependent upon a Shiny input. The `stat_chull()` wouldn't change with the changing color unless I got rid of the subset option. I tried re-specifying the hulls mapping by respecifying the color, but that didn't work. Can you point me in the right direction? I'll try to update this post with a minimal example soon if my question is too specific/complex

Comment: @ADuv  Don’t update this post. This question has been answered. If you have a new problem, start a new post.